# iOS Hide status bar for iPhone 6 and 6+

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7-statusbar

i am trying to hide the status bar only for iPhone 6 and 6+ this is what i tried so far.

```
if (screenWidth == 375) {
        // Remove status bar for iPhone 6
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES
                                                withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
    }else if (screenWidth == 414){
        // Remove status bar for iPhone 6 +
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES
                                                withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do (changing plist file):

```
set Status bar is initially hidden = YES
```

add row:

```
View controller-based status bar appearance = NO
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following line in viewDidLoad:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

and add new method

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
          return YES;
  }
```

also change info.plist file

```
View controller-based status bar appearance" = NO
```

And also add condition for iPhone 6 and 6 Plus.Here are the methods for iPhone 6 and 6 Plus:

```
/*=====================================================================================================================
 Checks if the device has 4.7 inch screen such as iPhone6 generation
 =====================================================================================================================*/
+(BOOL) ISiPhone6
{
    BOOL isIpad = ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    // we need to check the maximum of width and height because some screens (the camera view while scanning) we can
    // rotate to portrait or landscape and in the case the screen height and width flip
    return (!isIpad && MAX(screenRect.size.height,screenRect.size.width) == 667);
}

/*=====================================================================================================================
 Checks if the device has 5.5 inch screen such as iPhone6 plus 
 =====================================================================================================================*/
+(BOOL) ISiPhone6Plus
{
    BOOL isIpad = ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    // we need to check the maximum of width and height because some screens (the camera view while scanning) we can
    // rotate to portrait or landscape and in the case the screen height and width flip
    return (!isIpad && MAX(screenRect.size.height,screenRect.size.width) == 736);
}
```

it's works for me.

Answer (score 0):

First: set this flag **View controller-based status bar appearance** to YES in the info.plist or add it as a new row
Second: override this method`- (BOOL) prefersStatusBarHidden` in each VC info you want to hide or see the status bar. For child view controller you need also to implement this method `- (UIViewController *)childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden`
Third: if you are changing status bar appearance at runtime you need to call his method to trigger the animation `-setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate`
All this methods help you in create a granular control on status bar appearance.
If you need yo make the status bar disappear while launching just flag **Hide Status Bar** in your target general settings.

Answer (score 0):

Since you just want to hide Status bar only in iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus then You can do it like below. First add this in your class.

```
   #import <sys/utsname.h>
```

Then in your viewDidLoad method

```
 NSString *platform;
struct utsname systemInfo;
uname(&systemInfo);
platform = [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

if ( [platform  isEqual:@"iPhone6,1"]||[platform  isEqual:@"iPhone6,2"]){
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES
                                            withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51517879/6786974) for a similar question, you have to use the `windowLevel` of the `UIApplication` to hide/show the `statusBar`. Also we have to set the **Viewcontroller based appearance** property in the `info.plist` to NO.